# Kafka naming of main branch why "trunk" not "master"

Tags: git, svn, apache-kafka

I have found out that the default branch of Kafka's GitHub repository is the "trunk" branch. I am wondering why it is not "master" as git default ?

Also I managed to know that trunk is a major component in SVN, is there any history reason for this naming situation? I am totally new to svn since when I get to know version control, git is everywhere , it is already the most efficient and widespread one.

Also I am not what use what version of the code will be stored in the trunk branch? Can anyone give a clearer idea on that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`github.com/apache/kafka`](https://github.com/apache/kafka) is a mirror of the Apache repository.

And the "[Apache Kafka Release Process](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Release+Process)" refers to https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/kafka, a *Subversion* repository (whose default branch naming convention is `trunk`)